# Joomla site - show a message if the user who entered has a small screen resolution

Tags: javascript, joomla, screen, resolution

I would like a message to be shown to users who enter on my site from a for example  < 1100px width screen resolution.

Can somebody PLEASE help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an [article that detects the viewport](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/) (the space of the inside of the browser) rather than the screen size.

as for Joomla, i insert "quick fix scripts" inline, or externally linked, into the template that is currently in use.

---

provided in that snippet in the article, you have 2 variables you can use:`viewportwidth` and `viewportheight`

if you want to alert if width `< 1300`, insert this **after** the script provided above:

```
if(viewportwidth<1300){
    alert('not large enough');
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the script on my site and tested it and it shows correct the screen res.

Comment: Could you help me in setting so a message appears "alert popup" if the width is lower than 1300px PLEASE?? Thank you very much